# Tableau - Error when COUNT boolean T/F

Tags: tableau-api

My goal here is to count the # of True, False and NULL per day using my boolean calculation. Next step would be to calculate the percentage of each T, F, N with overall day.

Below is the visualization I would like to achieve but instead of blue dots, I would need the count of them in number.

[image]

Initially, I tried

```
IF [boolean] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

But only changing from True to 1, False to 0 and missing the NULL - not counting:

[image]

I also tried different Calculated Fields to get the count of it but always getting the same error:

```
SUM(IF [Field]=TRUE then 1 else 0 end)

COUNT(IF [Field]=TRUE then [ID] end)
```

ERROR:

[image]

Could someone please assist me with a Calculate Field or any other solution where I could get a count of T, F, and NULL that would also assist me with the percentage?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You're working too hard.

Just put SUM(Number of Records) on one shelf with DAY(Disconnected ...) on another, with the Boolean field that classifies data rows as > 0 or not on some other shelf, such as Color. No need for a table calc.

Here is an image of a solution posted at https://community.tableau.com/message/601862#601862

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply @Alex Blakemore. Unfortunately, it didn't work :(
I tried that before but no success. It seems missing the TRUE and NULL. It only shows the FALSE.

/Users/Desktop/2017-04-04_18-34-50.png

Comment: Why do you have a table calc for your boolean field? How is it defined? what is on the filter shelf?

Comment: /
Boolean:
if [DateDiff2] = 0 then FALSE
ELSEIF [DateDiff2] > 0 then TRUE
END
/
DateDiff2 is simple difference between SECOND(connect) and SECOND(disconnect)

Comment: But why is it a table calc? (shown by the triangle besides the field name on the shelf)? If you didn't mean to do that, you can right click on the field and clear the table calc.

Comment: BTW, your calculation could be simplified to just [DateDiff2] > 0

Comment: I meant it. The table calc is because the Datediff2 count should Restarting Every user ID.

Comment: Then how is the table calc defined? Did you use a quick table calc? which one?

Comment: I'm trying to attach the sample file in here but I can't. I posted it in the link below. Maybe helps clarify my calculations intentions. Once again, I appreciate your help to a newbie here.

[link](https://community.tableau.com/message/601346#601346)